# Как задать действия при запуске и закрытии?

Tags: java, netbeans, swing

В NetBeans (приложение Swing[Java]) нужно сохранять некоторые данные в XML при закрытии и восстанавливать при запуске приложения. Методы уже сделал, которые позволяют сохранить - восстановить. Как определить событие закрытия и открытия приложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приложение закрывается по крестику, на него вешаешь листенер - и если на него нажимают - выполняешь действия, а при открытии, еще проще, первый код, который выполняется при запуске приложения - должен быть метод открытия твоей XML-ки.

**UPD. #1**

```
 frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
     // ...
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {

         // [ТУТ ТВОИ ДЕЙСТВИЯ ПО ЗАКРЫТИЮ]
         System.exit(0);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Как привязать слушатель к крестику?

Comment: Я делал, как написано вот здесь. [Подтверждение закрытия JFrame](http://javaswing.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/jframe_close_confirm/). 
Не работает.

Comment: Разобрался, не тому фрейму делал слушателя. Спасибо!